# Tile size 16x16 of 32x32 with Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, hexagonal-tiles

I new to game development and Unity. I'm creating a tilemap to display my assets which I bought from itch.io. Now I have a tileset in both 16x16 and 32x32 pixel sizes. What is the difference between the two (except 'the size') since using them in a tilemap I do not see a size difference.

For example:

[image]

On the left you have 6 tiles from the 32x32 set and on the right from the 16x16 set.

Am I doing something wrong? I have a Scene in which I have added a 2D Object->Tilemap->Rectangular.

Thnxs

Comment: you probably didnt set the import settings